# fail to run first fabric application

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

when I run first fabric application in fabric-samples using the following instruction provided by [official Fabric document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html)：

```
npm install
```

it shows：

```
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

> pkcs11js@1.0.9 install /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/pkcs11js
> npm run build


> pkcs11js@1.0.9 build /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp configure build

make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/dl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/const.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/error.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/v8_convert.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/template.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/mech.o
../src/pkcs11/mech.cpp: In member function ‘void Mechanism::Free()’:
../src/pkcs11/mech.cpp:121:15: warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined [-Wdelete-incomplete]
   delete(param);
               ^
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_aes.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_rsa.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_ecdh.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/pkcs11.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/async.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11.node
  COPY Release/pkcs11.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'

> grpc@1.6.0 install /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

[grpc] Success: "/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v46-linux-x64/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
（omitting ）
npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Then I run command：`node query.js`  ，an error ocurred.

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:30:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I did above on ubuntu 16.04 through VMware software with node v6.9.5 and npm v3.10.10.
Please help，thx.

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
npm install grpc --save
```

to install grpc module to avoid the err.